# Why is Neovim's init file not working on my Mac?

Tags: vim, neovim

(Using MacOS) For some reason, the ~/.config/nvim file was not provided by default. So I created that directory and in it, the init.vim file.

The init.vim file has the following:

```
set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
let &packpath=&runtimepath
source ~/.vimrc
```

This is supposed to get Neovim to use the settings I wrote in .vimrc

For some reason, the settings I have wrote in .vimrc are not showing up when I use neovim. What's going on?

Answer (score 4):

Is the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variable defined in your shell? If so, Neovim will look for an `init.vim` (or `init.lua`) in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim` instead of `~/.config/nvim`.

Here is the pertinent help text from `:h init.vim`:

```
    The Nvim config file is "init.vim", located at:
        Unix        ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
        Windows     ~/AppData/Local/nvim/init.vim
    or if |$XDG_CONFIG_HOME| is defined:
                $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim
```

Comment: That variable is not defined for me. Does Mac follow the same rules with Unix systems? I'm not sure where else the init.vim file could be located

Comment: Yes macOS is considered a Unix OS and does follow the same config rules in Neovim. Seems like more info is needed here, how are you verifying that your `.vimrc` settings are being set? Can you add a simple `echo` in your `init.vim` and `.vimrc` to see which are being sourced properly?

Comment: Hey, sorry for getting back late. I typed "source ~/.config/nvim/init.vim" and I got this error. "Users/.../.config/nvim/init.vim:2: parse error near `&'".  Edit: It seems the .vim directory is empty, which causes an error when we are trying to access .vim/after. What should I do? Can I simply create an empty directory with the same name?

Answer (score -1):

On my Mac, it was because of the access permission with the `~/.config` folder. There was a red minus sign on the folder when viewed in Finder. I tried to open it and got this message:

> The folder “.config” can’t be opened because you don’t have permission to see its contents.

I figured this was the problem because when I ran Neovim with `sudo nvim`, all the customisations in the `init.vim` file were applied.

I removed the restriction on the `~/.config` folder by running this in the command line ([source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411718/how-to-access-to-the-config-folder-on-mac)):

```
sudo chown [user] ~[user]/.config
```

and then

```
chmod 711 ~[user]/.config
```

Change `[user]` with the name of your home directory.